# Probability of Poisson arrival in a vanishingly small interval

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Consider a homogeneous Poisson arrival process, and we look at the time interval $(t,t+\varepsilon]$ for a vanishingly small $\varepsilon>0$.

Why is it the case that the probability of more than 1 arrival in $(t,t+\varepsilon]$ is $o(\varepsilon)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability to have more than one arrival is then, assuming a rate $\lambda>0$ (seen as a constant),
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{ N(t,t+\varepsilon] > 1 \} 
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}\{ N(t,t+\varepsilon] = 0 \} - \mathbb{P}\{ N(t,t+\varepsilon] = 1 \} \\
&= 1 - e^{-\lambda \varepsilon} - e^{-\lambda\varepsilon}(\lambda\varepsilon) \\
&= \frac{\lambda^2\varepsilon^2}{2} + o(\varepsilon^2)
\end{align}$$
which is $o(\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Clement!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad this helped!